# Erlang client cannot ping server until server has pinged client

Tags: erlang, firewall, ping

**The problem**

I have two Erlang nodes, one on each of two computers.  I am launching each node with a unique sname and the same cookie.  When I try to net_adm:ping/1 from the client to the server it always times out, *unless* I first ping from the server to the client.

E.g., on the client:

```
(client@client_machine)1> net_adm:ping(server@server_machine).
pang
```

Then on the server:

```
(server@server_machine)1> net_adm:ping(client@client_machine).
pong
```

*Then* from the client again:

```
(client@client_machine)2> net_adm:ping(server@server_machine).
pong
```

I've allowed erl.exe and werl.exe through the firewall for all inbound and outbound connections on both machines.  I am unable to ping either direction with -name; I have to use -sname.

**The question**

Is this still a firewall issue or is this known behavior?  If it's known issue what's the workaround?  Have the server regularly try to ping any possible clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After double-checking everything I figured it out: I had firewall rules on the server to allow C:\Program Files\erl5.9.1\bin\erl.exe but was running C:\Program Files\erl5.9.1\**erts-5.9.1**\bin\erl.exe.

I feel stupid for missing something like that but figured I'd better own up to it so somebody else can benefit from this :/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you ping (the usual `ping` NOT the erlang ping) `server_machine` from `client_machine`, do you get `is alive` ? Usually, when nodes are NOT on the same computer/server, you need to use the `-name` and NOT `-sname`  option. 
If the two machines can see each other using the normal `ping` , then try starting the nodes using the `IP Adresses` of the machines. Lets say, that, `client_machine = 192.168.100.2` while `server_machine = 192.168.100.5` , the the nodes should be started like this:

```
# erl -name client@192.168.100.2 -setcookie mycookie
```

```
# erl -name server@192.168.100.5 -setcookie mycookie
```

Then do the `erlang ping` and see what happens. Also, since you are using `Resolvable names` i.e. `client_machine` , if you are on `UNIX / LINUX` you need to add the IP address and the name of the machine in `/etc/hosts` OR atleast make the two machines use the same DNS server, which can resolve those names. Also, when you read the [`net_adm`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html) documentation of erlang, you will find that [erlang has an equivalent of `/etc/hosts`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html#host_file-0)  as well.

Comment: Both machines have proper entries in both the machine hosts file as well as .hosts.erlang, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

do both "client_machine" and "server_machine" resolvable? you could check it with `ping server_machine` from command line.

since you do it on same physical instance and have different sname for each virtual node they should be both reachable, e.g. both have records in /etc/hosts (windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts in windows case)

Comment: I can command-line ping the server from the client and the client from the server.  The odd thing is that once the server has called net_adm:ping(Client), only then will the client's call to net_adm:ping(Server) succeed.